# Is it possible to add Android Thread Annotations to existing library methods?

Tags: android, android-annotations

I have not found any source which indicates that Android Annotations, like `@UiThread`, `@WorkerThread`, can be applied to library codes, for example, ActiveAndroid.

I want to enforce that all ActiveAndroid related code to be called in worker thread, but ActiveAndroid is library code, is there a way to add annotations to existing libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that use the library you want to use and put the AndroidAnnotation on the function you will have created.